# rsyslog only forwarding to remote server with logger -n and rsyslogd -n

Tags: linux, centos, configuration, rsyslog, troubleshooting

Having an issue with forwarding `rsyslog` to a remote server and I can't quite pin it down.

I don't think anything is wrong with my `rsyslog.conf`, seen below. I basically just added the line to forward to the remote server: *. * @@myserver.domain:10514

But when I try to trigger it with the logger, the message shows up in the log file but does not forward to the remote server. Watching `tcpdump`, it doesn't even attempt to send a message:

```
logger "test message"
```

If I actually specify the same remote server/port when I run logger, it works fine:

```
logger -T -P 10514 -n myserver.domain "test message"
```

It ALSO works if I use command `systemctl stop rsyslog`, and start it using:

```
rsyslogd -n
```

Although the remote log server doesn't seem to get exactly what I'd expect, I at least see the traffic in my `tcpdump` and something shows up on the remote log server from the client.

I do not have SELinux enabled.

rsyslog config:

```
#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional

*.* @@myserver.domain:10514

# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```